# How to Specify Src/Test/Resources folder as XSD resource path

Tags: java, xml, xsd

I am creating automated web services tests using java and REST Assured.

At the moment, I am validating the XML Response schema that I receive against an XSD file.

Below is my code:

```
InputStream ValidXsd = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("BR000AcceptSchema.xsd");

    RestAssured.given()
    .auth()
    .preemptive()
    .basic(theUsername, thePassword)
    .contentType(theContentType)
    .header("Accept",theContentType)
    .body(theXMLBody)
    .when()
    .post(theURL)
    .then()     
    .body(io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.matchesXsd(ValidXsd));
```

My issue is that this XSD file is currently stored in *src/main/resources*, but I need to move it to *src/test/resources*.

But, when I do this the test fails because the XSD file (*BR000AcceptSchema.xsd*) is not being picked up by the code.

Can someone please tell me how do I specify the code to look in src/test/resources for this XSD?

I think the issue is something to do with adding the XSD to the class/build path.

Comment: Is it test code (in `src/test/java`)?

Comment: Yes, the code in `src/test/java` tests the functional code

Comment: Then it should be discoverable, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Try to `getResource(...)` or `getResources(...)` first and check what's returned.
Another problem might be that the resource is not copied to the target folder for some reason. Check the target folder if the resource is there. If you're in IDE, check builder logs. If you're using Maven in Eclipse, check the m2 console.

Comment: @lexicore Hi, I've tried `System.out.println(new File("BR000AcceptSchema.xsd").getAbsolutePath());`, and that returns: **C:\Users\username\Desktop\Automation Testing\project-anem\BR000AcceptSchema.xsd**. I've also searched the project for this XSD file, and the only places it appears are in _project-name\src\test\resources\US46052_ and _project-name\target\classes\main\US46052_

Comment: @lexicore I've managed to self-diagnose the problem, the XSD file was contained in a sub-folder of src/test/resources!

Answer (score 0):

The XSD file was stored in a sub-folder, within src/test/resources, and I forgot to specify that in the file path.

The below code now works:

```
InputStream ValidXsd = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("US46052/BR000AcceptSchema.xsd");

RestAssured.given()
.auth()
.preemptive()
.basic(theUsername, thePassword)
.contentType(theContentType)
.header("Accept",theContentType)
.body(theXMLBody)
.when()
.post(theURL)
.then()     
.body(io.restassured.matcher.RestAssuredMatchers.matchesXsd(ValidXsd));
```

The only changes required were to the file path of the XSD in the first line of code